# Custom List Issues After SP2010 to SP2016 Migration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

We had a migration on our sharepoint farm from SP2010 to SP2016 and several things in our custom list forms really appear off and was looking to see if someone else had experienced this and might have a solution for correction.  We do have the opportunity to re-migrate so we can make changes on the SP2010 side to prepare for final migration which will happen at the end of next week.

Issue 1
any person or group field on our new or edit forms show up weird, the two icons for check names and browse people directors are now outlines in obnoxious blue lines

Issue 2
the check names function appears to work but the browse triggers an error to the screen JSON is unidentified and rather than getting the old pop-up window it builds an addition to the bottom of the screen for a people selection which is very ugly. And it does not appear that new addition to the bottom of the screen works it just spins.

Issue 3
One of our very standard forms shows up as completely unusable screen shot attached
[image]

Issue 4 
When we include a people or group field on a display form we get a weird icon in front of the actual value see attached
[image]

Issue 5
We also get a lot of these very strange pics pop up wherever we try to put the textname of a user or group on a page see attached
[image]

THese are all show stoppers for us to migrate so we are scrambling to try and find answers to fix on the receiving end or on the front end before we migrate again.

Thanks for any help provided

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you can't migrate / upgrade SharePoint 2010 sites directly to SharePoint 2016.

You may have to follow a 2-step approach. You can migrate SharePoint 2010 sites to SharePoint 2013 sites and upgrade SharePoint 2013 sites to SharePoint 2016. SharePoint Server 2016 will support upgrade from SharePoint Server 2013. To upgrade from SharePoint Server 2013 to SharePoint Server 2016, you can use the database-attach method to upgrade. This technique has one major restriction that all the site collections provisioned in backward compatible SharePoint 2010 (14) mode, must be upgraded to 2013 prior to upgrading to SharePoint Server 2016.

Alternateively, you can use a third-party SharePoint migration tool such as Vyapin's [**Dockit Migrator for SharePoint**](http://www.vyapin.com/products/sharepoint-migration/dockit/sharepoint-migration-tools) to directly migrate your sites from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2016.